# Why do parts of my views become unclickable if I translate its parent?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Using `Xamarin.Forms`, I have a `Grid` view to layout some numbers like a you would see on a phone.

[image: layout]

Here is the code I am using to create my `Grid` view along with the `Label`s I am inserting into it.

```
pinNumberGrid = new Grid {
    ColumnSpacing = 10,
    RowSpacing = 10,
    TranslationY = 30,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    RowDefinitions = {
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto }
    },
    ColumnDefinitions = {
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto },
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto },
        new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto }
    }
};


readonly Dictionary<string, string> pinNumbers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "1", "1" }, { "2", "2" }, { "3", "3" },
        { "4", "4" }, { "5", "5" }, { "6", "6" },
        { "7", "7" }, { "8", "8" }, { "9", "9" },
        { "a", "a" }, { "0", "0" }, { "b", "b" }
};

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

var tapListener = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapListener.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
{
    var numberHit = (sender as Label).Text;
    textEntry.Text += numberHit;
};

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pinKey in pinNumbers)
{
    var number = new Label {
        Text = pinKey.Value,
        TextColor = Color.White,
        FontSize = 35,
        WidthRequest = 70,
        HeightRequest = 70,
        XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
        YAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
        InputTransparent = false,
        BackgroundColor = Color.Gray
    };

    number.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapListener);

    pinNumberGrid.Children.Add(number, x, y);

    x++;
    if (x >= 3)
    {
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }
}
```

Everything is laying out properly. As you can see, I am adding a `TapGestureRecognizer` to each of the labels. This code definitely works because I put a *Debug.Log* in there and I am getting what I expect back in the *Application Output*.

The problem is that since I am doing a `TranslateY = 30` on the `Grid` view, it seems to be messing with the possible click area for the labels. After extensive texting with touches on my device, here is what the possible click range looks like (the bottom labels that are not in the green area don't respond to touch):

[image]

If I don't Translate the `Grid` view at all, the buttons work perfectly.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code above with `Xamarin.Forms` `2.0.1.6505` and there is no issue even when applying the `Translation=30` on the `Grid` object and clicking the lower part of the buttons (labels).

Try updating your `Xamarin.Forms` project to at least `2.0.1.6505` and retry, and hopefully you won't have this issue.

If you are still experiencing an issue, what outer container are you adding the `Grid` to?  I'm adding this to a simple `StackLayout` and am not experiencing any issues.

When you do update your project to a later version of `Xamarin.Forms` you will also have to change the following two lines:-

```
XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
YAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
```

to the following, as there was a couple adjustments done in `Xamarin.Forms`:-

```
HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
```

Comment: Looks like the reason was because of my Forms version number. I just reinstalled Xamarin on my computer and made a new project. I had neglected to update any components..